# Android definition of charge cycle?

Tags: battery, charging, battery-life

Battery life is measured in number of charge-discharge cycles. [Charge Cycle wiki](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charge_cycle) says

> Apple Inc. clarifies that a charge cycle means using **all the battery's capacity**, but not necessarily by full charge and discharge; e.g., using half the charge of a fully charged battery, charging it, and then using the same amount of charge again count as a single charge cycle"

This definition seems to be **Apple** oriented. My question is

**Does Android follow the same definition or is there a different definition ?**

Asking since I have both an iPad and Android (Samsung Galaxy) and was wondering if battery life is measured similarly or differently.

Comment: Plenty of references in our [charging tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/charging/info) (especially check the "Handling" and "Maintenance" sections there).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK I know there isn't any **Android specific** definition (would welcome corrections from others). Having said that, industry seems to treat this metric **differently**.

**Wikipedia  definition implies 100% discharge to count as one cycle, where as industry seems to treat 80% discharge to count as one cycle per sources below**

- [Battery Definitions & Terminology](http://www.radio-electronics.com/info/power-management/battery-technology/definitions-terminology.php) defines (emphasis added)

> **Cycle Life:**  The capacity of a rechargeable cell or battery changes over its life. The definition of the battery life or cycle life of a battery is number of cycles that a cell or battery can be charged and discharged under **specific conditions**, before the available capacity falls to a specific performance criteria - **normally 80% of the rated capacity**

- [What Constitutes a Discharge Cycle? section](http://batteryuniversity.com/learn/article/discharge_methods) , says (emphasis added)

> A discharge/charge cycle is commonly understood as the full discharge of a charged battery with subsequent recharge, but this is not always the case. Batteries are seldom fully discharged, and manufacturers often use the **80 percent depth-of-discharge (DoD) formula** to rate a battery. This means that only 80 percent of the available energy is delivered and 20 percent remains in reserve. Cycling a battery at less than full discharge **increases service life**, and manufacturers argue that this is closer to a field representation than a full cycle **because batteries are commonly recharged with some spare capacity left.**
>
> There is no standard definition as to what constitutes a discharge cycle (....)

To  summarise, Wikipedia definition seems **academic** while industry   treats it  **practically**

(Aside, [Charge Cycle Counter](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ch.cerebrum.ChargeCycleCounter), which measures battery charge cycles follows Wikipedia definition )

> Why I  **presume** Android follows industry definition

Apart from the two reasons mentioned above for 80%  discharge to be measured as *one cycle* (namely, real life charging and better battery life ), I suspect that battery manufactures would prefer this as it **boosts battery life cycle count by 20%** compared to Apple/Wikipedia definition.

Comment: Glad it helped :)