# Long term battery capacity degradation

Tags: battery, charging, battery-life, nexus-6p

I've had a Nexus 6P for about 14 months now and recently I discovered the app [AccuBattery](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.digibites.accubattery&hl=en), for those not familiar one of the features is to estimate the capacity of your battery by taking measurements on every charge (percentage indicated by your device and the charge measured in mAh). With using this app based on 122 charging sessions it estimates a full battery capacity of my device as about 2,300 mAh or about 68% of the originally designed capacity (3,450 mAh).

So my question is this: Is this amount of capacity degradation considered "normal" or "acceptable"?

The real world implication of this is that now I'm charging my device almost twice every day, which I suspect probably only amplifies the problem of degrading it faster. When I first got the device I could go roughly 2 days without having to recharge and I don't believe I changed my usage patterns since then.

Comment: Very similar [question on this site](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/167474/131553). Whether such degradation in your case is *normal or not* can't be answered since it depends on so many things- usage, charging practices, battery performance as per OEM of battery ( not made public) etc. Having said that, if you have to charge twice a day, its probably time for replacement

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the battery indeed passed through enough cycles to degrade. However, I don't think that there is a "normal" or "acceptable" level. If you feel that you are not satisfied with the battery, probably the time to change it has come