# Is it a bad idea to let your phone keep charging all the time?

Tags: battery, charging, battery-life

I read somewhere that long periods of charging can be bad for the battery and the best level to keep your battery at is around 50%. Is this true?

If it is then after how long will the battery show any signs of being affected?

Comment: There are two simple signs that your battery is affected: 1. the charge capacity is reduced 2. the battery is blowing up which usually leads to your phone getting a bulge or if this continues I have seem smartphones that "disassemble" them-self because the battery got larger and larger (that were older iPhone 6 connected 24/7 via USB to a computer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first part of your question, see [Ideal charging / discharging percentage for maximum battery life?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/156526/131553). Answers there explain in detail, so yes, it is *true*

Second part, after *how long...* depends on *how often* you charge it the wrong way, your usage (how many cycles of charge) etc and one cannot put a figure to it. Bear in mind that batteries even without being used lose a significant amount of life due to aging. So, it's a bit complicated to separate cause and effect. I don't think it will show up soon but maybe about an year or so (no backing to substantiate)

See answer here for more details [Battery capacity wear-down, and its relationship to charging practices](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/167474/131553)