# Is it safe for the battery to turn on the mobile data all the time?

Tags: wi-fi, charging, battery-life, mobile-data

I usually turn on my cellphone Mobile Data & WIFI all the time because I don't want to miss SMS and Emails. I'm afraid the battery could lose capacity over time if I keep turning on the Mobile Data/WiFi all the time or something might happen to my mobile. However, I believe modern electronics should be able to handle this kind of scenario. Does this apply to modern Android phones? Or do I need to continue disconnecting and connect only when needed?

*Note: I have an unlimited mobile pack.*

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on your **usage requirements**

- If you can't afford to miss mails or messages your wifi /data will be on and that will **certainly** lead to battery degradation. See [Battery capacity wear-down, and its relationship to charging practices](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/167474/131553), specifically the graph and it's explanation.
- Turning wifi /mobile data on/off isn't harmful. You can do that if you can live with missing messages or mails.
- If your device is rooted you can prevent battery degradation by making the device run from mains as explained here [Don't charge the battery but use connected power to run the phone](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/223812/131553) or at least keep the battery charged and discharged within safe limits as explained here [Ideal charging / discharging percentage for maximum battery life?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/156526/131553)
- If you don't want to root your battery, your battery will lose its life quickly and you would end up changing the battery or the device. Unfortunately, that's true.